# dataframe (product) correlations in R

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I've got 2 dataframes each with 150 rows and 10 columns + column and row IDs.  I want to correlate every row in one dataframe with every row in the other (e.g. 150x150 correlations) and plot the distribution of the resulting 22500 values.(Then I want to calculate p values etc from the distribution - but that's the next step).

Frankly I don't know where to start with this.  I can read my data in and see how to correlate  vectors or matching slices of two matrices etc., but I can't get handle on what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(42)
DF1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1500),150))
DF2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1500),150))

#transform to matrices for better performance
m1 <- as.matrix(DF1)
m2 <- as.matrix(DF2)

#use outer to get all combinations of row numbers and apply a function to them
#22500 combinations is small enough to fit into RAM
cors <- outer(seq_len(nrow(DF1)),seq_len(nrow(DF2)),
     #you need a vectorized function
     #Vectorize takes care of that, but is just a hidden loop (slow for huge row numbers)
     FUN=Vectorize(function(i,j) cor(m1[i,],m2[j,])))
hist(cors)
```

[image]

Comment: +1, could you however also add a bit of description to the code. That makes it even more useful for others (including the OP).

Comment: Hi Roland,  Thank you so much - it did the trick AND I've learnt a whole lot.  Cheers.  (Oh and thank you too Paul).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cor` with two arguments:

```
cor( t(m1), t(m2) )
```